# Can an image taken with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent be saved when system back button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, mediastore

I'm using the [MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) intent in my app to launch the camera and save the captured image.

My question is: is it somehow possible to store the image data captured within that camera intent, even when the user presses the system back button after taking a photo?

My app is in the leisure genre, so users are generally launching the camera to take photos of pretty landscapes, selfies, etc. 
I've now had a number of user complaints that they've lost photos they thought they'd taken due to their expectations of how the system back button works in the camera app.

For example, on my Nexus 6P if I launch the camera app, it looks like this:

[image]

Each time I hit the shutter button, the photo is saved to the gallery. I press system back and the camera app exits.

When I launch the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent from my app, it looks like this:

[image]

Almost identical to the camera app. But when I press the shutter button, the photo is not saved: instead I'm presented with this interstitial:

[image]

If I press the tick, great my image is saved, but if I'm a user that's familiar with the camera app, my instinct is to press system back to exit the camera once I've taken the photo, thinking that it has already been saved.

When I launch the intent I pass a temporary file URI in the cache directory as the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` parameter:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, this.temporaryFileURI);
```

Currently, when I handle the result, if the result is OK, I copy the file from the temporary location to the gallery location, and if the result is canceled (i.e. user pressed system back button), I display a toast indicating the camera action was cancelled.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        copyImageFile(this.temporaryFileURI, galleryUri);
    }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
        this.fail("Camera cancelled.");
    }else {
        this.fail("A problem occurred while taking the photo.");
    }
}
```

What I wanted to do was to change this so that the temporary file would be copied regardless if the back button was pressed:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK || resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        copyImageFile(this.temporaryFileURI, galleryUri);
    }else {
        this.fail("A problem occurred while taking the photo.");
    }
}
```

However, when the back button is pressed after pressing the shutter button to take a photo (`resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`), this results in a `FileNotFound` exception in `copyImageFile()` due to the temporary file not having been written by the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent.

Comment: No,

You will get Activity.RESULT_CANCELED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly no, when you launch an intent to an external app you lose all the control you have and there is no way of changing it's behavior.
When the user press the back button from that intent, it will return to your app, but you will get the `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` and no other information as you have already checked.

Your only option is to create your own camera activity instead of using the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` one

Comment: Thanks Julio, I thought this would be the case, but thought I'd cast a line out on SO anyway, just in case there was an off-the-wall workaround I'd missed. In the short term I'm using a pre-emptive dialog to inform users of the behaviour of the upcoming Camera activity, so for now I'll stick with that.